# put menu at the bottom of an image (inside image)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I need to put a menu attached to the bottom of an image, but not outside the image I use HTML, CSS with bootstrap 4, I have little knowledge of CSS I hope you can help me.

I have something like that(navbar down the image but outside )
[image]

and I need something like this (menu inside the bottom of the image)

[image]

I have this code

```
<img src="car.png">
        <ul>
                <li>
                    <a> HOME</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#contact">NEWS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: we can't do anything until you have something for us like code on which you have worked so far yet then we can update that code and it will be useful for you.

Comment: Impossible to help without a [mcve]. Nobody can  help fix html structure or css from only an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description I think that you want something like this.

Wrap your code in one div and set `position` to `relative`, than set to your `ul` tag `position` `absolute` with `bottom 0`;

Hope it helps...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent{
  position:relative;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-CGiYA8pN7HM/T_bKK0hOrpI/AAAAAAAACVQ/-ws96c-wkB8/s1600/audi-r8-v12-tdi-concept-2008-797153.jpg">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a> HOME</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#contact">NEWS</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#about">CONTACT</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```